# How is this site opening a new window

Tags: javascript, popup

Normally we can specify a target in the link or use javascript window.open to open a new window.

But when I access this site

www.wenxuecity.com  (It is a chinese site)

I could't find out how it opens each news in a new window.

no target in the link.
debug javascript doesn't show any call to window.open

Could someone tell me how it is implemented?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It has this code in the `head` section:

```
<base target="_blank">
```

That sets the default target for all links on the page.

Comment: any other way to popup a new window besides those 3 methods? Thanks

Comment: @user217428: You can set the target of a form and submit it.